# I'm trying to update a new instance of a class but it's updating already created ones

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

```
List<Food> userOrders = [];
```

Food

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int pq;
  int quantity;
  bool favourited;
  List<Variation> variations;
  Variation? selectedVar;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.pq, this.waitTime, this.score,
      this.price, this.quantity, this.variations, this.about, this.favourited,
      {this.highlight = false});
}
```

This is in a different widget, when a tile is tapped, the selectedVar is changed but its suppossed to be for a new instance

```
onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (widget.food.variations[index].selected) {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    } else {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    }
                    if (selectedIndex == index) {
                      widget.food.selectedVar = widget.food.variations[index];
                    }
                  });
                },
```

FoodQuantity

I'm trying to create the `+` button work in such a way that when the Variation is changed a new instance of food is created and added to `userOrders`. But instead when I tap on a new variation it updates the ones already added to `userOrders`.

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // print();
                  if (widget.food.selectedVar == null) {
                    errorDialog(
                      context,
                      'ERROR',
                      'Please select a variation',
                    );
                  } else {
                    if (selectedVars.contains(widget.food.selectedVar)) {
                      if (userOrders.contains(widget.food)) {
                        context.read<FoodCount>().increment(widget.food);
                        context.read<Counter>().update();
                      } else {
                        userOrders.add(widget.food);
                        context.read<Counter>().update();
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    } else {
                      selectedVars.add(widget.food.selectedVar);
                      Food newFood = Food( //Is this the ideal way to create a new instance?
                        widget.food.imgUrl,
                        widget.food.desc,
                        widget.food.name,
                        widget.food.pq,
                        widget.food.waitTime,
                        widget.food.score,
                        widget.food.price,
                        widget.food.quantity,
                        widget.food.variations,
                        widget.food.about,
                        widget.food.favourited,
                      );
                      userOrders.add(newFood);
                      context.read<Counter>().update();
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  '+',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white38,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Checkout

I get the "Null check operator used on a null value" on line 60 and 107 but when I remove it, it says "Null check operator used on a null value"

```
Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: Image.asset(
                                userOrders[index].selectedVar!.imgURL,
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                          ),
```

I can't use the bang operator and I can neither use it. What should I do?

```
Text(
                                userOrders[index].selectedVar!.title,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              ),
```

Comment: you are missing calling setState after adding item, and you can use `${ userOrders[index].selectedVar?.title,}`